# Why is this post marked as Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

It seems that [**this post**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/144681/7424) has been marked as Community Wiki.  I'm assuming that was done by mistake.  Is there a way to change it back?  It seems like a valid question to me, worthy of the answerer to get reputation points.

Comment: Maybe they accidentally clicked the check box when they answered? I note the *question* isn't, just the answer, and the edit history indicates the answerer is the one who made it CW.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too after I posted this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could see no likely reason for the author making this particular answer Community Wiki (CW), and so I too am assuming that it resulted from a mis-click or a misunderstanding of when CW is used.

Consequently, I have removed the CW status from the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/144684).

Comment: There actually is a purpose to CW status: respondents use it when they wish to encourage the community to improve on or augment their post.  Are you sure the original poster of this answer did not intend it to be CW?

Comment: @whuber I cannot be certain so acted on what I believed to be the most likely scenario.  With the user's rep around 300 I suspect they have been around long enough to be aware of CW but by not including a statement like "making this CW to encourage others to improve my answer", they may well not have been aware of its consequences.  I realize now that I should have alerted them to the modification (so they could reinstate CW if they wish).  I'll do that now by linking this Q&A there as a comment.